# Why does the compiler cast automatically without going further in the inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oop, inheritance

While I try to run following code snippet, it’s executing wrong overload method. I'm confused why it does that?   *[`testB.TestMethod(testValue)` method execute the  `public double TestMethod(double value)` method]*

```
public class TestA
{
    public int TestMethod(int value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class TestB : TestA
{
    public double TestMethod(double value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

static void Main( string[] args )
{
    TestB testB = new TestB();

    int testValue = 3;

    testB.TestMethod(testValue);
}
```

Do you have any idea about this ?

Is there are any way to call TestA class method via the TestB instance without cast as TestA.?

**But it is not happen in JAVA and C++**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the specification, under "Overload Resolution":

> ...and methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable (§7.6.5.1).

Comment: And even if you make the method in `TestA` `virtual`, and `override` that overload inside `TestB`, this still happens.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen indeed, the words immediately before the above (in the "...") are: "...the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include methods marked override (§7.4),"

Answer (score 9):

> **Inheritance**
>
> Inheritance can cause a confusing effect. When the compiler goes
>   looking for instance method overloads, it considers the compile-time
>   class of the "target" of the call, and looks at methods declared
>   there. If it can't find anything suitable, it then looks at the parent
>   class... then the grandparent class, etc. This means that if there are
>   two methods at different levels of the hierarchy, the "deeper" one
>   will be chosen first, even if it isn't a "better function member" for
>   the call.

source: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Comment: So you have to cast to `TestA` if you want to call a member with the same name on `TestA` which has an implicitly compatible type?

Comment: @Charleh, Yes, if you want to call the overload in `TestA`, you have to cast it to `TestA`. I tested it.

Comment: You mean Without casting cant we call TestA class method ryt?

Comment: True, I would implement it otherwise, like first looking for the exact match, then the most applicable match up to the the parent class.